# How to make web page elements ALL increase in size without displacing elements?

Tags: html, css

So basically what I am trying to copy is what Twitter has setup on their page when you try and do CTRL+ or increase size of the web page.

http://twitter.com/

Currently, my elements will displace upon zoom in and I have yet to find a solution.... This has been a long lasting issue I haven't got a fix to yet.

All help is appreciated..

**HTML:**

```
<div class="h_headerbar">
<div class="h_navbar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Publishing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
background-color:#565656;
max-height:750px;
min-height:545px;
right:0;
left:0;
}
.h_headerbar{
width:100%;
background-color:black;
height:125px;
}
.h_navbar{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.h_navbar li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px solid #111;
    margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.h_navbar li:hover{
background-color:#191919;
}
.h_navbar a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:table-cell;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2M56B/)

All help is appreciated... I have a project I would like to get started on, but I don't want to design an entire page to know that the way I built it will cause element displacement...

Comment: I don't think there is anything you CAN do to prevent slight displacement. Your browser is making the adjustments on the page, so unless you disable zoom, don't think there is a way to 'fix' it. When fractioning page elements, especially with odd numbers, you will have pixels fall between, browser has to chose one way or another.

Comment: Also, twitter uses Twitter Bootstrap, which you can use too, but that plays a huge part in the way the interface doesn't wrap and stack when you zoom.

Answer (score 0):

i understand whats going on. What you want is for your list to adjust to whatever screen size your browser is on weather you shrink the screen ore even expand it. As well as when you zoom!

So you need to add some responsive CSS to your script.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 660px){}
```

Set the dimensions for your div within the brackets. Your div losses its place at about 660px so you cam control what happens with your nav and li elements as the screen reaches that width.

[html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)